# Reversing exponents in lua

Tags: math, lua

I have a algorithm to calculate the desired exp for reach a level. But I didn't know how get the desired level based on his EXP.

```lua
local function NextLevelXP(level)
    return math.floor(1000 * (level ^ 2.0))
end
print(NextLevelXP(7)) -- output: 49000
```

Now I want the level based on his EXP, with something like:

```lua
local function MagicFunctionThatWillLetMeKnowTheLevel(exp)
   return --[[math magics here]]
end
print(MagicFunctionThatWillLetMeKnowTheLevel(49000)) --output: 7
print(MagicFunctionThatWillLetMeKnowTheLevel(48999)) --output: 6
```

I've tried some worse and weird algorithms, but no success.

Comment: `math.floor((exp/1000)^0.5)`

Comment: Works like a charm, could u explain why `^0.5` even I'm using `^2.0`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `^0.5` is the reverse for `^2`

Comment: in general reversing an exponent `x` is by doing the exponent `1/x` which is `1/2` or `0.5` in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simplified:

```lua
local function NextLevelXP(level)
    return math.floor(1000 * (level ^ 2.0))
end
```

the `math.floor` is not necessary if `level` will always be an integer.

to reverse the formula you can do:

```lua
local function CurrentLevelFromXP(exp)
    return math.floor((exp / 1000) ^ (1/2))
end
```

Here it is necessary to floor the value as you will get values between levels, (like 7.1, 7.5, 7.8). To reverse the multiplication by 1000 we divide by 1000, to reverse the exponent we use the inverse of the exponent, in this case 2 becomes 1/2 or 0.5

---

Also, as a special case, for `^2` you can simply `math.sqrt` the value.